# Вебвизор и wordpress

Tags: wordpress, яндекс-метрика

Вебвизор Яндекс метрики не показывает работу с панелью /wp-admin, можно ли как-то добавить ее отслеживание?

В настройках вебвизора указана запись страниц из браузера по регулярному выражению regexp:.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, счетчик не совсем правильно установлен на сайте. Обычно в примерах установки предлагают поместить код в `footer.php`. В этом случае он срабатывает только на внешней части сайта. На админ страницах `footer.php` не загружается. Для установки счетчика также на админ-страницы, следует поместить код ниже в `functions.php` вашей темы.

```
// Счетчик Яндекса
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'yandex_counter' );
add_action('in_admin_footer', 'yandex_counter');

    function yandex_counter() {
        ?>
            <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function (d, w, c) {
                    (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
                        try {
                            w.yaCounter00000000 = new Ya.Metrika({
                                id:00000000,
                                clickmap:true,
                                trackLinks:true,
                                accurateTrackBounce:true,
                                webvisor:true
                            });
                        } catch(e) { }
                    });

                    var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
                        s = d.createElement("script"),
                        f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
                    s.type = "text/javascript";
                    s.async = true;
                    s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

                    if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
                        d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
                    } else { f(); }
                })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
            </script>
            <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/00000000" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
            <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
        <?php
```

}

Обратите внимание на то, что функция счетчика добавляется в два хука: `wp_footer` (для лицевой части сайта) и в `in_admin_footer` (для админ-страниц).

В самом коде счетчика в примере я заменил код моего сайта на `00000000`(3 вхождения).